# Could I write private property as well as private variable in same class extension?

Tags: objective-c

A bit confused with class extension given by Apple's Objective-C tutorial. It is said class may have its private property like

```
@interface SomeClass()

@property NSString* privateProperty

@end
```

while I may add so-called custom instance variable to class extension like

```
@interface SomeClass()
{
  NSString* instanceVar
}
@end
```

I was adding them together in same class extension by tutorial implication like

```
@interface SomeClass()

@property NSString* privateProperty

{
  NSString* instanceVar
}

@end
```

which results into compiling error by Xcode. Am I misunderstand tutorial?

Comment: @Daij-Djan Your comment doesn't make sense. This is exactly the sort of question that should be on SO. And so what if the syntax issue isn't specific to a class extension. The OP is asking a clear programming question about the Objective-C programming language.

Comment: Putting aside the snooze-inducing meta discussion, in practice, the `@property` declaration can be regarded as a replacement to, a superset of the curly-braced instance variable declaration.  If you're trying to learn the language and not its history, use `@property <type>ivar`.  Think of it as a one-line declaration of instance var (called `_ivar`), a getter that can be used like `instance.ivar`, and a setter that can be used like `instance.ivar = <some value of type>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

vice-versa. variables belong right after the interface.

```
@interface SomeClass () {
    NSString* instanceVar
}

@property NSString* privateProperty

@end
```